# How to set a background colour for uservoice widget?

Tags: uservoice

This looks like an obvious feature, but somehow I cannot find how to do it: https://developer.uservoice.com/docs/widgets/options/

Could you tell me if it is possible at all to change the background of the uservoice widget to color different from the white one. Ideally, to set it transparent.

Thanks a lot,
Olena

Answer (score 0):

You can not change the background color of the widget. I asked this question from uservoice support and they told you can't.

Comment: Add a link/screenshot/exact quote from Support's response to make your answer more credible